# How to get Vim to highlight non-ascii characters?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to get Vim to highlight non-ASCII characters. Is there an available setting, regex search pattern, or plugin to do so?

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Using range in a `[]` character class in your search, you ought to be able to *exclude* the ASCII hexadecimal character range, therefore highlighting (assuming you have `hlsearch` enabled) all other characters lying *outside* the ASCII range:

```
/[^\x00-\x7F]
```

This will do a *negative* match (via `[^]`) for characters between ASCII `0x00` and ASCII `0x7F` (0-127), and appears to work in my simple test. For extended ASCII, of course, extend the range up to `\xFF` instead of `\x7F` using `/[^\x00-\xFF]`.

You may also express it in decimal via `\d`:

```
/[^\d0-\d127]
```

If you need something more specific, like exclusion of non-printable characters, you will need to add those ranges into the character class `[]`.

Comment: In decimal: `/[^\d0-\d127]`

Comment: @Bohr That's a nice addition. I'll edit it in above.

Comment: great! saved the day! one of the indentation character got pasted into my python code and the unicode error start killing me. was hard to detect among the same character used by vim plugin!

Answer (score 41):

Yes, there is a native feature to do highlighting for any matched strings. 
Inside Vim, do:

```
:help highlight
:help syn-match
```

`syn-match` defines a string that matches fall into a group. 
`highlight` defines the color used by the group. 
Just think about syntax highlighting for your vimrc files.

So you can use below commands in your .vimrc file:

```
syntax match nonascii "[^\x00-\x7F]"
highlight nonascii guibg=Red ctermbg=2
```

Comment: you don't need to put the `:` in front of commands in your vimrc.

Comment: `termbg` doesn't seem to be a legal command in VIM 7.3 as installed on Ubuntu Server 12.10.

Comment: Then `termbg` doesn't seem to be a legal parameter in VIM 7.3 as installed on Ubuntu Server 12.10.

Comment: Indeed, regular terminal `term` cannot have background color, while color terminal `cterm` can.

Comment: removed termbg but you could add ctermfg, guifg, etc to also control the foreground.

Answer (score 19):

For other (from now on less unlucky) folks ending up here via a search engine and can't accomplish highlighting of non-ASCII characters, try this (put this into your .vimrc):

```
highlight nonascii guibg=Red ctermbg=1 term=standout
au BufReadPost * syntax match nonascii "[^\u0000-\u007F]"
```

This has the added benefit of not colliding with regular (filetype [file extension] based) syntax definitions.

Comment: I get `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: au BufReadPost * syntax match nonascii "[^\u0000-\u007F]"
Press ENTER or type command to continue` Linux mint 17.3

Comment: Though the goal is stated of **not** conflicting with already defined syntax definitions, if you **want** it to you can add `containedin=ALL` to the end of the last line, making it `au BufReadPost * syntax match nonascii "[^\u0000-\u007F]" containedin=ALL`.  I find the distraction worth it (when unicode is allowed), the original answer here does **not** catch things such as non-ascii code inside of an `if` statement...

Comment: It is always safer to enclose your `autocmd BufRead ....` in an autogroup in vim, unless you have a very good reason not to...

Answer (score 8):

This regex works to highlight as well. It was the first google hit for "vim remove non-ascii characters" from [briceolion.com](http://briceolion.com/145/removing-non-ascii-characters-through-vim/) and with `:set hlsearch` will highlight:

```
/[^[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]/
```

Comment: The question is asking to **highlight** non-ascii characters, **not removing them**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer. It wasn't much of a stretch to see that this regex also answers the question in a way that is different from other answers. My original answer was `:%s/[^[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]//gc` which highlights first, then replaces.

Comment: `[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]` are character classes which do _include_ non-ascii characters on UTF-8 locales.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested also in the **non printable** characters use this one: `/[^\x00-\xff]/`

I use it in a function:

```
 function! NonPrintable()
   setlocal enc=utf8
   if search('[^\x00-\xff]') != 0
     call matchadd('Error', '[^\x00-\xff]')
     echo 'Non printable characters in text'
   else
     setlocal enc=latin1
     echo 'All characters are printable'
   endif
 endfunction
```

Comment: Your function does not work in here, it does not highlight and it also mess the encoding. Why are you changing the local encoding?

Comment: Try to change `enc` to `fenc`. I changed the encoding because my default encoding is (was in 2013) latin1. The function doesn't highlight the non printable characters if the characterset is latin1. Too see the highlighting you must have the key `ERROR` in your color syntax file. This is mine: `hi Error     guifg=Black      guibg=Orange`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other answers on this topic and the answer I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682324/set-item-to-higher-highlight-priority-on-vim/27687580#27687580) I've added this to my `.vimrc`, so that I can control the non-ascii highlighting by typing `<C-w>1`. It also shows inside comments, although you will need to add the comment group for each file syntax you will use. That is, if you will edit a zsh file, you will need to add `zshComment` to the line

```
au BufReadPost * syntax match nonascii "[^\x00-\x7F]" containedin=cComment,vimLineComment,pythonComment
```

otherwise it won't show the non-ascii character (you can also set containedin=ALL if you want to be sure to show non-ascii characters in all groups). To check how the comment is called on a different file type, open a file of the desired type and enter `:sy` on vim, then search on the syntax items for the comment.

```
function HighlightNonAsciiOff()
  echom "Setting non-ascii highlight off"
  syn clear nonascii
  let g:is_non_ascii_on=0
  augroup HighlightUnicode
  autocmd!
  augroup end
endfunction

function HighlightNonAsciiOn()
  echom "Setting non-ascii highlight on"
  augroup HighlightUnicode
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme *
        \ syntax match nonascii "[^\x00-\x7F]" containedin=cComment,vimLineComment,pythonComment |
        \ highlight nonascii cterm=underline ctermfg=red ctermbg=none term=underline
  augroup end
  silent doautocmd HighlightUnicode ColorScheme
  let g:is_non_ascii_on=1
endfunction

function ToggleHighlightNonascii()
  if g:is_non_ascii_on == 1
    call HighlightNonAsciiOff()
  else
    call HighlightNonAsciiOn()
  endif
endfunction

silent! call HighlightNonAsciiOn()
nnoremap <C-w>1 :call ToggleHighlightNonascii()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow none of the above answers worked for me.

So I used `:1,$ s/[^0-9a-zA-Z,-_\.]//g`

It keeps most of the characters I am interested in.

Comment: This _deletes_ the characters, where the op asked for _highlighting_.

Comment: don't you mean [^0-9a-zA-Z,\-_\.], i.e. \-?

Answer (score 0):

Someone already have answered the question. However, for others that are still having problems, here is another solution to highlight non-ascii characters in comments (or any syntax group in the matter). It's not the best, but it's a temporary fix.

One may try:

```
:syntax match nonascii "[^\u0000-\u007F]" containedin=ALL contained |
            \ highlight nonascii ctermfg=yellow guifg=yellow
```

This has mix parts from other solutions. You may remove `contained`, but, from documentation, there may be potential problem of recursing itself (as I understand). To view other defined patterns,  `syn-contains` section would contain it.

```
:help syn-containedin
:help syn-contains
```

---

Replicated issue from: [Set item to higher highlight priority on vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682324/set-item-to-higher-highlight-priority-on-vim/43183947#43183947)