# Combining vim lookahead and lookbehind constraints in syntax highlight rules

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regex-based syntax highlight rule that combines both [lookahead and lookbehind](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Regex_lookahead_and_lookbehind) constraints for a match.

For some reason, however, I can only get it to work with certain characters.

For example, I can match the `b` in `%abc` using:

```
syn match TestMatch /\vb(c)@=&(\%a)@<=b/
hi Purple ctermfg=92 guifg=#8700d7
hi!     link TestMatch     Purple
```

However, when I try to match the `b` in `#abc`, it doesn't work:

```
syn match TestMatch /\vb(c)@=&(#a)@<=b/
```

Anyone happen to know what the issue could be?

Comment: Both work fine, [here](https://i.imgur.com/WVWVVuG.png).

Comment: Thanks! That suggested it must be another syntax rule that is overriding the one I defined.. Sure enough, when I remove an earlier line inheriting from another syntax (i.e. `runtime! syntax/markdown.vim`), the highlighting works! I was hoping the use of `hi!` would help to give my rule precedence, but that doesn't seem to be the case.. At least this gives me something to work with though..

Comment: Got it! Based on a suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682324/set-item-to-higher-highlight-priority-on-vim I was able to get it to match by adding a `containedin=` statement to indicate the match is found inside one of the markdown hilight groups.. will post answer above.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the issue here was that an earlier statement in my syntax file was causing "#foo" to be matched, and therefor already assigned a color:

```
runtime! syntax/markdown.vim
```

In that file, there is a syntax rule:

```
syn region markdownH1 matchgroup=markdownH1Delimiter start="##\@!"      end="#*\s*$" keepend oneline contains=@markdownInline,markdownAutomaticLink contained
```

Which also matches things like "#abc"..

Based on a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682324/set-item-to-higher-highlight-priority-on-vim), I was able to get around this by specifying that my rule is *contained* in the rule defined in markdown.vim, i.e.:

```
syn match TestMatch /\vb(c)@=&(#a)@<=b/ containedin=markdownH1
```