# Post-receive cd no such file or directory

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I have a `post-receive` hook in which I perform some git checkouts based on the branch being pushed. Before proceeding to do some more business logic, I need to change the working directory to a directory stored in a variable. However, I keep getting a "No such file or directory" error despite the directory being existent...

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=/home/username/directory
cd $dir
```

The git folder itself is located at /home/username/git/project

I'd like to keep the cd command as generic as possible using a fully qualified path (this path is fixed, the git directory can be anywhere), so no `cd ../../directory` stuff please...

Anyone got ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Is there a space in the path?  Does `cd "$dir"` work better?

Comment: Eh? A fully-qualified path is the _least_ generic thing you could have, since it only works with that single location; a relative path means you can relocate the subtree and have your code still work, so long as the relevant components stay in the same location relative to each other.

Comment: Anyhow, `set -x` is your friend. If you have hidden characters in your file (say, a stray DOS newline), it would show up in `set -x` output. But first, add the missing quotes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry I sort of formulated the 'generic' part incorrect. The path in the declared variable is always fixed throughout the script. By saying generic I wanted to achieve the possibility to put this post-receive script in any git directory in the server (therefore no ../.. stuff)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Using `set -x` it seems cd is trying to call this path: `/home/username/directory\342\200\250`...

Comment: @Propaganistas, ...and does it show up that way in the assignment command, or only in the `cd`? Either way, you have nonprintable characters in your script -- so the _actual_ script doesn't match with what you put in your question here -- but answering that will tell you which line they're on.

Comment: If you're on a GNU system, by the way, you can run `cat -A yourscript` to display its text in a way that makes nonprintable characters visible. `less yourscript` should do the same, or likewise a good editor (such as vim) when appropriately configured; http://stackoverflow.com/a/26209681/14122 would be a good place to start if your editor of choice is vim.

Comment: I performed the procedure as described [here](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix) en now it's working properly. I still find it strange that these non-printable characters were introduced in the file as I was using Sublime Text on OSX. Anyhow, thanks for the help!