# remove unicode characters but keep all special and English characters with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to use `preg_replace` to remove all unicode characters including Persian characters from a string and keep English and all special characters. The way I know to do it is :

```
preg_replace('/[^<>()/\* a-zA-Z0-9_.-]/u', '', $string);
```

But, I don't really want to include all special characters inside []. Is there any shorter way?!

Comment: What characters specifically do you mean by _special characers_? You include `<>()/*` in your pattern - Do you want a larger set than those?

Comment: One approach you may take is to remove everything falling outside the standard US ASCII range (using a method [similar to this for Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987362/how-to-get-vim-to-highlight-non-ascii-characters))

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes! exactly. of course, I want to keep everything, and just remove unicode characters. So, I don't want special characters to be removed. Thus, as I know,  I have to include all special characters inside the brackets to have this.

Comment: It still isn't clear to me what constitutes special characters, but does `preg_replace('/[^\x00-\x7f]/u', '', $string)` produce something like you want?

Comment: That keeps ASCII 00-10, including NUL, backspace, tab, etc. You can shorten the start of the range to something like `\x20` to begin with SPACE

Comment: I'll put it as a proper answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove everything but characters falling in the basic ASCII range, you may use a pattern [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16987522/541091) to match the range by HEX codes.

```
// Given a string with characters in and outside ASCII:
$s = "abcde啅cde衸xtzሴbb()*&bԴ";

// Match HEX 00-7F and remove characters outside that
// by inverting with ^
echo preg_replace('/[^\x00-\x7f]/', '', $s);
// Prints:
// abcdecdextzbb()*&b
```

Using HEX 00-7F will also include the start of the ASCII range, therefore covering things like `NUL`, terminal bell, backspace, etc.  You may consider starting with ASCII 32 (hex 20) at `SPACE` if you don't want your output to include those special non-printable control characters.

```
echo preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7f]/', '', $s);
```