# Uncaught Syntaxerror: invalid or unexpected token for Unicode line separator \u2028

Tags: javascript, unicode

Does anyone knows how javascript processes unicode character and decides that it is invalid?

[image: errorimage]
As shown in attached image, somebody has entered the text which has \u2028 character in a `<textarea>`.

Now this throws an error when the page is opened and goes responsive.

Can I check text for such characters at compile time?

I can't use regex directly as that would save me from one character only or cant use range of separators or control characters of unicode because my application is localized and I don't want to take the risk of skipping data by mentioning range of chars.

So I wanted to know would it be possible to check string by validating just like javascript does at runtime?

Comment: What do you call compile time? What kind of document is this? And how do you generate it? Where is the *textarea* you talk about, and how is it related to the javascript code?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721861/remove-unicode-characters-but-keep-all-special-and-english-characters-with-pre  ?

Comment: The line on which red dot is seen was added in textarea.
this is page opened from console.
compile time as in when form is submitted that time can this text be validated for unicode character. basically should check for valid javascript string object

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I generate html code with EJS like this:

```
window.myState = <%- JSON.stringify(locals) %>
```

Where `locals` contains special character that causes syntax error.
As a workaround I've changed it to:

```
window.myState = JSON.parse(`<%- JSON.stringify(locals) %>`)
```

The trick here is to use **ES6 template string literal** which is **not supported** for example in IE11.