# Hightlight keyword when grep

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, grep

I have a script that highlight the keyword when I grep it and it works great.

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT_LOG="/Sandbox/myfile/somelogs.log"
grep --color=always $1 myfile.txt
```

If I was to do the same thing but write the output to a file, then it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT_LOG="/Sandbox/myfile/somelogs.log"
grep --color=always $1 myfile.txt >> $OUTPUT_LOG
vi $OUTPUT_LOG;
```

I tried vi or less but I still don't see my keyword being hightlight.  I'm confuse. Any reason why it wouldn't work?

tks

Comment: `grep --color=always` is for terminal display... no reason to expect any text editor to understand it as well

Comment: you can do `grep --color=always 'searchstring' input_file | cat -v` to see the highlighting

Answer (score 0):

vi might not be a good test for your output-to-file.

Instead, try [`less -R $OUTPUT_LOG`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=less+-R+%24OUTPUT_LOG)

The highlighting in grep works by inserting non-ASCII control characters to change the formatting in your terminal.

I do not think vi will interpret those characters as color control (since it has its own syntax highlighting system).

see [How to get Vim to highlight non-ascii characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987362/how-to-get-vim-to-highlight-non-ascii-characters), if you really want to go that route.